# Custom directive to populate dynamic select box AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-options

I've got the following controller that basically calls a http get service and assigns the data to a `show_data` scope variable

```
.controller('forms_controller', function($scope, Form) {

Form.get().then(function(data){
    $scope.show_data = data;
});


});
```

The `scope.show_data` is then pushed to this view ..

```
<div ng-repeat="(key, value) in show_data | orderBy:'key' " >
<div ng-switch on="value.Type" >
    <div ng-switch-when="attributes" >
        <div ng-repeat="(key2, value2) in value | orderBy:'key' ">

            <div ng-switch-when="Date" >                            
                <label class="item item-input">
                    <span class="input-label">{{value2.Label}}</span>
                    <input identifier="{{value2.Identifier}}" type="date">
                </label>
            </div>

            <div ng-switch-when="Select" >
                <label class="item item-input item-select">
                    <div class="input-label">
                    {{value2.Label}}
                    </div>
                        <select codelist="{{value2.CodeList}}" identifier="{{value2.Identifier}}" >
                    </select>
                </label>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Which basically checks the data based on the input type and spits out the different form elements based on the data. My problem is I am faced with is with the select box... Each select box has an id [codelist in this case] to the `ng-options` that should be displayed however, I'd first need to make another http get call to fetch this data before populating the ng-options ...
Please also note that there might be more then one select box per form.

I was thinking of using some kind've custom directive to achieve this?
Any help would be highly appreciated :)
Thank You

Comment: You don't use show_list anywhere

Comment: So this works? I don't get what the problem is.

Comment: How would i go about using that codelist value and then executing a http.get request to populate the options?

Comment: Each select box is populated with a unique id (codelist) . Each codelist refers to a json set of data on a remote server

Comment: Do you have to wait for user input to know which http.get you have to do?

Comment: No .. it needs to populate each select box with its options based on the codelist value when the form initialises

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that the server sends you an "incomplete" object. You need to do additional get requests to "complete" your object.

So this is what you should do: in your controller, iterate over your object and do the additional get-requests and store the results in something that you can call in your html with `value2.items`.

You don't have to wait with setting `$scope.show_data` untill all the data is fetched. Angular's two-way binding will synchronize the html as soon as the additional info is available.

Something like this should work.

```
var n = 0;
for (;n < data.length; n += 1) {
    var values = data[n].value
    var i = 0;
    for (;i < values.length; i += 1) {
        // GET based on values[i].CodeList
        $http.get(...)
        .success(function (data2) {
             values[i].items = data2
             // Retrieveable in HTML as value2.items
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Okay - so if i itterate over the data object and get the codelist data per select box. How would i bind that data to each select box dynamically?

Comment: @DarrynSmith I added some example code to show what I mean